# How to initialize members of App without running the App (main)?

Tags: java, scala, initialization

I have a class `MyClass`, which extends `App`. The thing is that, inside `MyClass`, there is a variable `myValue` that I need to initialize, without actually running the app. The reason for this is because I want to run unit tests of the methods of `MyClass` in a non-interactive way.

```
class MyClass extends App {
    val myValue = "A value that I need to run the unit tests"

    def myMethod: Unit = "A method that needs to be unit-tested and uses " + myValue

    /* ... main (interactive) code that is not supposed to run in the unit test... */
}
```

So, the question is: How can I initialize members of App without running the app (main)?

Comment: Is there any reason why you choose extending `App` over defining `main` method: `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = ...` ? There is no such problem with later approach.

Comment: It seems to be the "scala way" of doing things. I'd switch to the Java way in a heartbeat, but I'm wondering if there's a less hacky way of doing it...

Comment: Actually, both approaches are equally "scala". The `main` method approach is even used in "hello, world" example on scala site: http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html

Comment: Well, for now I'll use your approach... I won't accept your answer because, although it provides a solution, it doesn't really answer the question. Or are you saying that it's impossible to initialize members of `App` without actually running the app?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid words like "impossible". Maybe it's possible, but the solution will involve some hacks, because it clearly violates contract described in scaladocs of `App` trait.

Comment: If I were you, I'd go with cleaner and readable solution instead of introducing additional levels of complexity trying to use functionality in unintended way, just because it seems more "scala".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From scaladocs of `App` trait:

> **==Caveats==**
>
> It should be noted that this trait is implemented using the `DelayedInit`  functionality, which means
>   that fields of the object will not have been initialized before
>   the main method has been executed.

It seems that your only option is to declare main method `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = ...` as you would do in Java instead of extending `App`.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid... Shouldn't we stick to the scala way of coding? Is there really no way to make App behave the way I want it to?

Comment: It is not like extending `App` trait is the only valid and "scala" way of creating main entry point, it is just for convenience.